# In pandas, how can I read an Excel sheet that has an specific name in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

So basically I have a ton of files that change each week that passes by, I want to know if there is a way that I can go ahead and specify to the python script to grab that sheet that contains an specific column name, so for example

1. For file `test.xlsx` I have the following structure

sheet 1

| columnA | columnB | columnC | Columnd | ColumnE | ColumnF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dsf | sdfas | asdf | sadf | asfdsd | sdfasf |
| sdfsd | sadfsd | asdfsd | asdfasd | asdfdsf | sdfadf |

Sheet 2

| jira_tt | alignID | issueID | testID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dsf | sdfas | asdf | sadf |

As you can see the excel file has 2 sheets, however this is just an example as some file may have more than 2 sheets or the names of the sheets will change, as stated above I want to read all the sheets in all the files that have the keyword "jira" on their columns, so far I have been able to create a script that reads all the files on the target folder, however I don't have a clue on how to specify the sheet as I needed, here is part of the code that I've created so far

```
import glob as glob
import pandas as pd

#using glob to get all the files that contains an xlsx extension
ingestor = glob.glob("*.xlsx")

for f in ingestor:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)

df
```

Any kind of assistance or guidance will be appreciated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include all your files as `DataFrame's` you can create a list to store it and use `merge()` method to split files in one `DataFrame`, for example:

```
import glob as glob
import pandas as pd

ingestor = glob.glob("*.xlsx")

df = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right), [pd.read_excel(data) for data in ingestor])

print(df.isin(['jira']))
```

if want just files that contains a specific word (like `"jira"`), you need to evaluate with a conditional using `any()` method on each iteration and merge data:

```
ingestor = glob.glob("*.xlsx")

df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in ingestor:
    data = pd.read_excel(f)
    df.insert(data[data.str.contains("jira"))
   
print(df)
```

Comment: the issue is that I need to look for specific columns that contains "jira", not look at the whole data, another issues is that I have like 20 files that all have different names on the sheets, so I was wondering if I can search the specific column from all the sheet and files and then get the whole column with its data.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use `insert()` and `df.insert(data[data.str.contains("jira"))`, this would check for `Series` and search for a specific word (`'jira'`), you should have a `dataframe` with only columns that contains a specific **string** *value*

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `pd.read_excel(f)` returns the first sheet by default. If you want to get another sheet or more than one, you should use the `sheet_name` argument of `pandas.read_excel`, [read here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

For the case that the number of sheets is unknown, specify `None` to get all worksheets:

```
pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
```

Note that now a dict of DataFrames is returned.

To get the sheets with a column that contain "jira", simply check the column's name:

```
for f in files:
    df_dict = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=None)
    for sheet_name, df in df_dict.items():
        for column in df.columns:
            if 'jira' in column:
                # do something with this column or df
                print(df[column])
```